# Sequence to Generating Function

Tags: generating-functions

I was given a sequence (0, 0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16). I am tasked with finding the generating function. So far I have reached this point: 
  A(x) = x^2 + 2x^3 + 4x^4 + 8x^5 + 16x^6 + ...
-xA(x) = x^2 +  x^3 +  x^4 + x^5  +   x^6 + ...

A(x) - xA(x) = x^3 + 3x^4 + 7x^5 + 15x^6
Any input on where to go from here would be appreciated.

Comment: Try factoring an x^2 out of A(x) and see if something seems familiar

Comment: I assume you know how to handle a geometric series?

Comment: @Mike I wouldn't assume that =p

Comment: @Tim You're right it does look familiar. It looks like the sum of an infinite geometric series. However, the one difference in this problem compared to others I have done is that each constant seems to be increasing by a multiple of two and I am unsure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Well, like I mentioned in my comment, you have a geometric series.  You can find the formula [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula).  Basically, you were on the right track, but the ratio between terms is $2x$.  Try multiplying $A(x)$ by $2x$ and subtracting.

Comment: Ahh.. Gotcha! I'm left with A(x) - 2xA(x) = x^2. When I take out an A(x) I get A(x)(1 - 2x) = x^2. When I divide both sides by (1-2x) I get x^2/(1-2x). Thanks!